# How to migrate test database

Tags: django, testing, django-migrations

So, I have some project on django. Now, I need to run existing tests in project.
I am use `./manage.py test` and get this message:

[image]
Then I try to migrate database as written in message above and I see django try to apply migrations for 'origin' database.

By default for tests django create new database for testing with 'test_' prefix.

So, my question is: How can I apply migrations to 'test_' database?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your code for the test do you have a setup method?

Comment: @hansTheFranz, actually there are several test files. Yes, there are exist setup method in some of files, but nothing about db connection.

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as images, paste them as formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by adding an entry into the settings for `DATABASES`

So, for example the `default` and our additional entry:

```
{
  'default': {
    'NAME': 'myapp',
    'USER': 'myapp',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 5432,
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS': True,
    'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
    'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    'OPTIONS': {},
    'TIME_ZONE': None,
    'TEST': {
      'CHARSET': None,
      'COLLATION': None,
      'MIGRATE': True,
      'MIRROR': None,
      'NAME': None
    }
  },
  'my_test': {
    'NAME': 'test_myapp',
    'USER': 'myapp',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 5432,
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
    'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    'OPTIONS': {},
    'TIME_ZONE': None,
    'TEST': {
      'CHARSET': None,
      'COLLATION': None,
      'MIGRATE': True,
      'MIRROR': None,
      'NAME': None
    }
  }
}
```

And then running the migrate command with `--database`:

> --database DATABASE   Nominates a database to synchronize. Defaults to the "default" database.

Like so:

```
./manage.py migrate --database my_test
```

And if there are multiple from a parallel run, then just loop the extra entries into the settings dictionary as well.